# How to Fetch Value from XML document and store it in a variable using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

Am new to Automation and am using Selenium with Java.

I have a Problem where i need to go through an XML file find a Node and read the value in that node. And i need to compare the value with the Input String.

Can someone please help me how to read the xml file and fetch the value from the xml and store it in a variable.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<cXML timestamp="2017-06-15T18:26:00.271+05:30" payloadID="7500610099-0-PORQ" version="1.2.011">
-<Header>
+<From>
+<To>
+<Sender>
</Header>
-<Request deploymentMode="test">
-<OrderRequest>
+<OrderRequestHeader type="new" orderType="release" orderDate="2017-06-15" orderID="7500610099-0">
+<ItemOut requestedDeliveryDate="2017-06-02" quantity="1" lineNumber="5">
+<ItemOut requestedDeliveryDate="2017-06-02" quantity="1" lineNumber="5">
+<ItemOut requestedDeliveryDate="2017-05-23" quantity="1" lineNumber="1">
+<ItemOut requestedDeliveryDate="2017-05-23" quantity="1" lineNumber="2">
-<ItemOut requestedDeliveryDate="2017-05-23" quantity="9" lineNumber="3">
-<ItemID>
<SupplierPartID>1*VP470</SupplierPartID>
</ItemID>
```

I Need to Read the Value inside the node `<SupplierPartID>`

Thanks,
Satish D

Comment: is this a separate xml file which you will read it via normal java from local?

Comment: @santhoshkumar - Yes this is a separate file and i will read it from shared location. But for now lets assume i have this file on my desktop and reading it from local.

Comment: why you want to use selenium? you could parse the xml using a xml parser or Xpath to select only that Element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Java inbuilt libraries to  create a regex pattern and search for that in the String(data in the file). The below code might give you some idea.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    //Change the path for the file
    String content = new Scanner(new File("/home/santhoshkumar/Desktop/sample.xml")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

    //System.out.println(content);

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<SupplierPartID>(.*)</SupplierPartID>");    
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);  

    while (matcher.find()) 
    {    
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));    

    }    
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Below Code works like a Gem.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();                   

          //Parsing of xml is done here
            Document doc = builder.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\User_Name\\Documents\\My Received Files\\PDSL_ABM.xml"));

            //Here we get the root element of XML and print out
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("SupplierPartID");
            int totalSupplierPartID =list.getLength();
            System.out.println("Total no of SupplierPartID : " + totalSupplierPartID);



          //Traversing all the elements from the list and printing out its data
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

          //Getting one node from the list.
            Node childNode = list.item(i);
            System.out.println("SupplierPartID : " + childNode.getTextContent());
            }
```