# How to Read Value from XML document and store it in a variable using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, openscript

I'm new to Automation using Selenium with Java.

I have a problem where i need to go through an XML file find a Node and read the value in that node. And i need to compare the value with the Input String.

Can someone please help me how to read the xml file and fetch the value from the xml and store it in a variable.

This is what i have in xml :

[image]

In the Image 01 i need to read the value in `ChassisModuleOptionRequest partner_item=` and store the value in an array.

Below is the code i tried.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();                   

//Parsing of xml is done here
Document doc = builder.parse(new File("C:\\Users\\Satish_D1\\Documents\\My Received Files\\PDSL_ABM.xml"));

//Here we get the root element of XML and print out
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("ChassisModuleOptionRequest");
int totalPartnerItem =list.getLength();
System.out.println("Total no of Partner Item : " + totalPartnerItem);         

//Traversing all the elements from the list and printing out its data
for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) 
{

    //Getting one node from the list.
    Node childNode = list.item(i);
    System.out.println("Partner Item : " + childNode.getTextContent());
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us your work?

Comment: @DebanjanB i have updated the Question with the piece of code i tried.

Comment: I suggest you to use this similar approach.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587006/how-to-fetch-value-from-xml-document-and-store-it-in-a-variable-using-selenium-j/44588824#44588824

Answer (score 0):

We can use Java inbuilt libraries to create a regex pattern and search for that in the String(data in the file). The below code might give you some idea.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
{
  //Change the path for the file
  String content = new Scanner(new File("/home/santhoshkumar/Desktop/sample.xml")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

  //System.out.println(content);
  //Arraylist to store the values
  ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
  //Change the pattern.
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<CChassisModuleOptionRequest partner_item=\"(.*)\">");    
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);  

  while (matcher.find()) 
  {    
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));    
    values.add(matcher.group(1));
  }    
}
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: had an errror in below line                                   
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<CChassisModuleOptionRequest partner_item="(.*)">");                    Changed it to                                                 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("partner_item="+"(.*)"+"");                              but the code is not working as expected.

Comment: Forgot to escape the double quotes. Now corrected it.